# Randomly pairing elements of a vector in R to count unique arrangements

Tags: r, combinations

Background:

On [this combinatorics question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2694519/521868), the issue is how to determine the sample space: the ways 8 different soccer teams can be paired up for the next round of competition. Two different answers have been advanced for that part of the problem: 28 (see comments OP) and 105 (see edit within OP and answer).

I'd like to do this manually to try to hone down on the mistake in whichever answer is incorrect.

---

What I have tried:

```
teams = 1:8
names(teams) = c("RM", "BCN", "SEV", "JUV", "ROM", "MC", "LIV", "BYN")
split(sample(teams), rep(1:(length(teams)/2), each=2))
```

Unfortunately, the output is a list, and I wanted a vector to be able to run something like:

```
unique(...,MARGIN=2)
```

Is there a way of doing this in an elegant manner?

---

After a now erased answer (thank you), I would go with

`a <- replicate(1e5, unlist(split(sample(teams), rep(1:(length(teams)/2), each=2))))`

to simulate 100,000 random samples, and later run

`unique(a, MARGIN = 2)`.

But how can I account for the fact that the order of the 4 pairings of opponents doesn't matter, and that `LIV-BYN` and `BYN-LIV`, for example, is the same pairing (field advantage notwithstanding)?

Comment: Will 'unlist' work for your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
> u = ncol(unique(replicate(1e6, unlist(split(sample(teams), rep(1:(length(teams)/2), each=2)))), MARGIN = 2))
> u / (factorial(4) * 2^4)
[1] 105
```

The idea of `unlist` is from @Song Zhengyi, and if his answer is un-deleted, I'll accept it. The complete answer is in the lines above.

`u` needs to be divided by 4! because

```
BCN-RM, BYN-SEV, JUV-ROM, LIV-MC
```

is exactly the same as

```
LIV-MC, BCN-RM, BYN-SEV, JUV-ROM
```

or

```
BCN-RM, LIV-MC, BYN-SEV, JUV-ROM
```

etc.

The term `2^4` is to avoid over-counting since for every possible unique draw, each one of the pairings can be flipped without loss (discarding field advantage): `BCN-RM` is the same as `RM-BCN`, and there are 4 pairs in each draw.

---

If field advantage is a consideration (real life)...

```
> u/factorial(4)
[1] 1680
```

we end up with 1,680 possible draws.